# Is it ok to tap a 220v line to create an outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens

I have a 220v stovetop that someone tapped to add an outlet to the island. That means this outlet is 220v. It's been like this for years and has never been an issue.

I'm replacing the stovetop (which is why I'm looking at it). Is it ok to have a "regular" outlet with 220v?

Location: USA

Comment: Location in the world is very important. Edit into your question.  I am assuming Europe, since North American outlets usually work with 120 volts, so 220 volt would not play nice with what you plugged in.   North American stove circuits should only have the stove on it(no tapping off of outlets/other stuff).  Do not know about Europe regulations/codes/laws.

Comment: I'm in the USA -- I knew I was supposed to include that but forgot :-) -- So safe to assume it's not safe?

Comment: How many kW is your stove, and do you know if the circuit's a 40A or a 50A circuit?

Comment: I doubt that you actually have a 220V outlet that has "never been an issue" for years.  You'd be very lucky, it would be ok if the only thing you've plugged into it, for years, is small electronics such as phone chargers that don't mind 220V.  Anything like a blender or cake mixer or kettle would, at best, blow a fuse inside.  There is probably ALSO 120V available on that circuit and used for the outlet.  But the outlet is not ok for many other reasons, as noted in other comments and answers.

Answer (score 3):

North America just the stove is suppose to on that circuit.

Imagine what they did was to only tap one hot and the neutral(plus ground) for120 volts.

Usually not safe since outlets and their wires/cable should be limited to a 15 or 20 amp circuit breaker.

The stove is probably 40 amps breaker, so not safe.

To keep that handy outlet, will need a new circuit from the panel with 12 gauge wire/cable and a 20 amp breaker.  Kitchen outlets usually need to 20 amp.

Comment: To add to this, a lot of stoves have one or two regular outlets on top of them somewhere - but those are safe because the stove will have a fuse or breaker in it at the appropriate 15 or 20 amps.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not, that's how you blow things up.

If you want a 240V outlet, that's really not a problem, they make those.

[image]

However the circuit breaker must be matched to the socket size - except that 2 or more 15A sockets are allowed on a 20A breaker due to an exception. NEC 210.21. You cannot hang 15-20A sockets on a 30-50A breaker.

The bigger problem is the old range circuit may be a "3-wire" with 2 hot wires and a neutral, and no ground whatsoever.   That should not be used for anything, until ground can be retrofitted.